# Store log file / console output of Jenkins job build in dreamhost

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dreamhost

We've some Jenkins jobs. when a new build is created in Jenkins, we want to store the console output or log file in dreamhost (http://www.dreamhost.com).

we already have **buckets**, **access_key** and **secret_key** in dreamhost.

How can we **store the console output of every build** by shell commands, plugin or any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a post step shell script, you can get the console log file with a wget command:

```
wget -O my_build.log ${BUILD_URL}consoleText
```

Next, you can upload your log file with a [SCP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin) or a [FTP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin) command.

Comment: @ Bruno, is it possible to redirect the console output continuously when job is running in jenkins and see the content of console log with `tail -f my_build.log`?

Comment: The logs are written in the jobs/my-job/builds/999/log file (where 999 represents the current build number). There is no permalink to point on this log file so it's hard to tail with a fix path :(

Comment: @ Bruno, it helped! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve it from the logs written in path : /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/#job_name/builds/#build_id/log.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to use the wget option because the domain is not accessible from Jenkins itself but I could copy the file from Jenkins folder in "Post build task" via:

```
cp "${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log" console-output.log
```